# Working with the additional cell lines in NCI-60

Tags: cancer, cell-line

NCI-60 has additional [cell lines](https://dtp.cancer.gov/discovery_development/nci-60/cell_list.htm), but when I get results from [CellMiner](https://discover.nci.nih.gov/cellminer/) they are not included in there.

Namely, the genes such as:  `DLD-1`(Colon), `KM20L2`    (Colon), `M19-MEL` (Melanoma), don't show in the results of CellMiner.

Is there away to include these additional lines in the correlation calculations?